# Convert 24 hours date format to 12 hour format in R

Tags: r

I have a 24 hours time format vector.

```
time24 <- c("10:43:12", "10:54:25", "11:54:21", "23:07:20")
```

I need to convert it to 12 hour format.

```
"10:43 AM", "10:54 AM", "11:54 AM", "11:07 PM"
```

I tried using strptime but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `format` around the `strptime` output to get the expected output.

```
format(strptime(time24, '%H:%M:%S'), '%I:%M %p')
#[1] "10:43 AM" "10:54 AM" "11:54 AM" "11:07 PM"
```

Comment: You're about to get your 100K Stack Overflow party.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thanks, hopefully another week or so.

Comment: How about going in the other direction, e.g., 1 PM to 13:00?

Comment: timey = format(strptime(temp, format='%I:%M:%S %p'), format='%H%M') #Drop seconds.